# Image view not aligned with Button

Tags: android, xamarin

I am unsure about how to align correctly the image view; the arrow image with the "Select Treatment" button text. I tried to set the margin for the `imageview` but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Anyone can help with this?

Below is the screenshot of the image and code for the layout.

[image]

Request_Appointment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/sublayout_Toolbar" />
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="35dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/request_HospitalLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/request_HospitalLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:text="@string/hospital" />
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/request_HospitalField"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:background="@drawable/editText_line" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/request_DateLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_HospitalLayout">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/request_DateLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:text="@string/pref_date" />
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/request_DateField"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="@string/select_date"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:background="@drawable/editText_line" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/request_DentistLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_DateLayout">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/request_DentistLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:text="@string/pref_dentist" />
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/request_DentistSpinner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                            android:prompt="@string/select_dentist"
                            android:background="@drawable/editText_line" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/request_SessionLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_DentistLayout">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/request_SessionLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:text="@string/pref_session" />
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/request_SessionSpinner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                            android:prompt="@string/select_session"
                            android:background="@drawable/editText_line" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                  <LinearLayout
                      android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentLayout"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_below="@id/request_SessionLayout">

                    <Button
                       android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentsBtn"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_below="@id/request_SessionLayout"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                       android:text="@string/select_treatments"
                       android:textAllCaps="false"
                       android:background="@color/transparent" />

                    <ImageView
                      android:id="@+id/appt_ArrowImage"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                      android:layout_gravity="right"
                      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                      android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                      android:scaleX="0.75"
                      android:scaleY="0.75" />
                  </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/request_RemarksLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_TreatmentLayout">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/request_RemarksLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:text="@string/remarks" />
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/request_RemarksField"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top|left"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:background="@color/.8_white" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/request_SubmitBtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_RemarksLayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:text="@string/submit"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:background="@color/blue" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/light_blue" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change `request_TreatmentLayout` linear layout from `vertical` to `horizontal`.

Comment: BTW you have use `layout_below` and                       `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in `LinearLayout` which is not applicable for it. It uses in `RelativeLayout` only.

Answer (score 0):

change your `request_TreatmentLayout` **orientation** `android:orientation="vertical"` **to** `android:orientation="horizontal"` **like this**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/request_SessionLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentsBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/request_SessionLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:text="@string/select_treatments"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appt_ArrowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:scaleX="0.75"
        android:scaleY="0.75" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_below="@id/request_SessionLayout">

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/request_TreatmentsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                        android:text="@string/select_treatments"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"/>

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/appt_ArrowImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/request_TreatmentsBtn"
                        android:scaleX="0.75"
                        android:scaleY="0.75"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```